# how to use clock_gettime

Tags: c, time, include

I am trying to use the `clock_gettime` function, but can't figure it out what are the needed headers (or what am I doing wrong if it's not a question of headers).
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /*for CLOCK_REALTIME? */
#include <time.h>

#define NANO_TO_MILLI(N) ((N)/ 1000000)


struct TimeStruct
{
    time_t sec;        
    time_t nano;  
};

typedef struct TimeStruct TimeStruct;

void getTime (char* _timeStr);

int main()
{
    char* time;
    getTime(time);
    printf("%s\n", time);
    
    return 0;
}


void getTime (char* _timeStr)
{
    time_t milli;
    TimeStruct *curTime;
    struct tm* info;
    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, curTime);
    milli = NANO_TO_MILLI(curTime-> m_nano);
    
    info = localtime(&(curTime-> m_sec));
    sprintf(_timeStr, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d.%d", 1900 + info->tm_year, info->tm_mon, info->tm_mday, info->tm_hour, info->tm_min, info->tm_sec,  (int)milli);
    
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> implicit declaration of function clock_gettime
>
> CLOCK_REALTIME undeclared

What am I missing?

I am compiling with gcc (linux) with ansi and pedantic flags

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: Aside: `TimeStruct *curTime; .... clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, curTime);` is suspicious.  I'd expect `TimeStruct curTime; .... clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &curTime);`

Comment: Another minor: `"%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d.%d"` --> `"%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d.%03d"` and `info->tm_mon` --> `info->tm_mon+1`.

Comment: Note that `clock_gettime()` is a non-standard function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile with `-ansi`, several POSIX standard functions become unavailable.  To have access to them you need to compile with `-std=gnu99`.  That gives you C99 plus POSIX and GNU extensions.

Besides that, `clock_gettime` expects a pointer to a `struct timespec`, but you're supplying a custom type instead.  Get rid of the custom type and use the standard one.

Also, the pointer you're passing to `clock_gettime` is not initialized.  This function expects this parameter to point to an instance of `struct timespec`.  As as, the function will write to whatever address the  uninitialized pointer has.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of creating a pointer that points nowhere, create a struct instance and pass in its address.

```
void getTime (char* _timeStr)
{
    time_t milli;
    struct timespec curTime;
    struct tm* info;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &curTime);
    milli = NANO_TO_MILLI(curTime.tv_usec);

    info = localtime(&curTime.tv_sec);
    sprintf(_timeStr, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d.%d", 1900 + info->tm_year, info->tm_mon, info->tm_mday, info->tm_hour, info->tm_min, info->tm_sec,  (int)milli);

}
```

You're also writing to an uninitialized pointer in `main`.  Use a `char` array large enough to store the string.  Also, use a name other than `time` as that masks the same of a system function.

```
int main()
{
    char timeStr[50];
    getTime(timeStr);
    printf("%s\n", timeStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, *curTime);` should be `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &curTime);`.